# execute file denied

Tags: permissions, chmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to 'chmod' on an NTFS ( or FAT32 ) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

I am a beginner on ubuntu 11.10,
I want to execute some program named `./Pro` but when i try:

```
$ ./Pro
```

I get the following error:

```
$Bash: ./Pro : Permission Denied.
```

When I try to change the permissions, by running: `$sudo chmod +x Pro`, nothing changes!
In fact when I do `$ls -l Pro` the result is:

```
$-rw------- 1 hafez hafez 7251 2012-03-19 07:44 Pro
```

How can I run my file?

Comment: Add to your question that you are a ROOT user. For a beginner I find it odd that you would go directly to using ROOT.

Comment: check the permissions of the directory you are in! (so `cd ..` and then `ls -l|more`)

Comment: 4 drwx------ 1 hafez hafez     4096 2012-03-19 07:44 tor-browser_en-US
30096 -rw------- 1 hafez hafez 30817839 2012-04-13 21:00 tor-browser-gnu-li
nux-i686-2.2.35-9-dev-en-US.tar.gz

Comment: my drive is created on windows and its filesystem is ntfs is it related? because when i copy that Pro file to home it worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the output to the following command `mount | grep -i nexec` I think your filesystem is mounted with a noexec option.

From the man page:

```
noexec Do not allow direct execution of any binaries on the mounted filesystem.
```

To solve this (until next reboot)

```
mount -o remount,exec your_filesystem
```

To make it survive a reboot, you'll have to edit /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 1):

right click in the file -> permissions -> allow executing fila as a program
=)

in command line: try with sudo!

```
sudo chmod +x Pro
```

Comment: sudo is not the problem

Comment: Did you try the graphical way? The first solution I told you.
If it not work, make sure that nobody more (program or human) has the file in his possesion.

Comment: To know if the file are opened or in posession by one program, execute in a terminal:
lsof | grep "filename" without the quotes
if something is in the output, then the file is possesed by this program. So you have to close this program/procces before changing the permissions.
Are I explained well? =)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
chmod a+x Pro
```

Or, for fun:

```
chmod 755 Pro
```

Comment: nothing changed!